# Why is the fold action necessary in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, reduce, fold

I've a silly question involving `fold` and reduce in `PySpark`. I understand the difference between these two methods, but, if both need that the applied function is a commutative monoid, I cannot figure out an example in which `fold cannot be substituted by`reduce`.

Besides, in the PySpark implementation of `fold` it is used `acc = op(obj, acc)`, why this operation order is used instead of `acc = op(acc, obj)`? (this second order sounds more closed to a `leftFold` to me)

Cheers

Tomas

Answer (score 14):

**Empty RDD**

It cannot be substituted when `RDD` is empty:

```scala
val rdd = sc.emptyRDD[Int]
rdd.reduce(_ + _)
// java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection at   
// org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$apply$ ...

rdd.fold(0)(_ + _)
// Int = 0
```

You can of course combine `reduce` with condition on `isEmpty` but it is rather ugly.

**Mutable buffer**

Another use case for fold is aggregation with mutable buffer. Consider following RDD:

```
import breeze.linalg.DenseVector

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array.fill(100)(DenseVector(1)), 8)
```

Lets say we want a sum of all elements. A naive solution is to simply reduce with `+`:

```
rdd.reduce(_ + _)
```

Unfortunately it creates a new vector for each element. Since object creation and subsequent garbage collection is expensive it could be better to use a mutable object. It is not possible with `reduce` (immutability of RDD doesn't imply immutability of the elements), but can be achieved with `fold` as follows:

```
rdd.fold(DenseVector(0))((acc, x) => acc += x)
```

Zero element is used here as mutable buffer initialized once per partition leaving actual data untouched.

> acc = op(obj, acc), why this operation order is used instead of acc = op(acc, obj)

See [SPARK-6416](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6416) and [SPARK-7683](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7683)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you please elaborate a little more the mutable buffer example? Is there a similar example in PySpark?

Comment: Since `zeroElement` is created every time `fold` is called and is not part of the data it can be safely mutated. PySpark is partially immune to possible effects of mutating data inside RDD so it is hard to find a good Python example. It is a detail of implementation not a part of the contract though.